# NAS Drive Not Correctly Reporting Files, Directories from a DOS/Command prompt in WIN7

Tags: linux, prompt, ext3, dir

I have an NAS drive on my network, and it works just fine.  I can access every file on it with WIN7.

However, when I go to a command prompt and perform a directory command, the command reports 0 files and 0 directories.

I am told the NAS is an Ext3 format and is readable only using a Linux machine.

I was wondering if someone else had a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 is not able to access ext3 drives without 3rd party software installed, so if the drive uses ext3, how are you able to access the drive via the GUI? More than likely the NAS drive is not formatted as ext3.

How are you using *dir* to access the NAS? What command are you using? Have you mapped the drive to a drive letter first (via the `Windows Explorer / Tools menu / Map Network Drive` option)?